# Managing null safety plugin along with non null safety plugin in flutter

Tags: flutter

please is it possible for one to use a null safety plugin along with non null safety plugin together in a project , if yes how because I am looking for a way to merge the both together without clash

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to say that, you want to implement null safety but also want to use null for your variables?

null safety accepts null value, but, you have to mention that a variable can be null. This can be done like below:

```
final String name = 'John';              // cannot be null
final String? name = null;            // can be null
```

You can refer to https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety .

hope this answers your question.

Comment: No I mean , if there's a way to use  flutter plugins that support null safety along with other flutter  plugins that does not support null safety together in your flutter project

Comment: No. that is not possible.